# Is cooling needed to be able to overclock the Pi further?

Tags: overclocking, cooling

I've only managed to overclock my Pi to 1.3 GHz, but this guy here http://www.overclock.net/t/1404207/extreme-cooled-raspberry-pi got it up to 2.4GHz. Is it the cooling that makes it possible to get up to that high? I couldn't overclock my Pi any more because, if I increased it more, it would crash at startup. Would cooling help with this too?
Usually, it seems that you only need cooling to keep the CPU cool as overclocking heats it more then normal, but if it crashes at startup would more cooling actually help?

Comment: As I understand it, it is the cooling however impractical those methods seem ;) I guess that an Atom based Micro PC running at 2GHz or so is way more handy and easy to use... I wonder how many cooling cycles the RPi's SOC will survive.

Comment: The cooling definitely had a positive effect, and as you mention variations in the production and assembly will mean that the amount of overclocking will vary between boards. The bigger question is how stable is the final system. Great it runs at 2.4GHz, but if it only runs for 30 seconds it is useless for its intended purpose. Since someone has already gone to 2.4GHz you don't even get bragging rights (no one remembers who finished second).

Answer (score 1):

Extreme overclocking has always required extra cooling or some. Mainly USA PC users have even resorted to water cooled systems.

However, I would suggest, if the stock Pi can't handle whatever you are trying to achieve, chances are you shouldn't be using the Pi.

If you MUST use a Pi, go for the quad core ARM 7 Pi 3B+. (it's said to be 7x times faster)

Comment: "7x faster" is a bit of an idealization.  As with other multicore systems, the fastest it can go is still whatever the base Hz is.  You cannot do one task four times faster on a quad core; but you can do four things four times faster, because they will all get done at the same time.  So it all depends on the nature of the task.

Comment: Yup. Upto x times faster. As demonstrated here. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27813/should-i-provide-additional-parameters-for-make-on-raspberry-pi2

Comment: One core is about 3x faster on new Pi